# Pull data from another apreadsheet where Row and Column are strings

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, importrange

I am trying to pull data from a different sheet in google sheets by matching row and column header 
EG

SheetB

```
LOC    prox   dist    qty
sjc    12     15     19
dfw    10     16      8
atl
ord
```

In sheet a, I am trying to ref dynamically in sheet b 
something like:

```
cell g1 = "Prox"
cell a3 = "SJC"
```

in cell g3 the formula should be the equivalent of `"select g3 where col1=a3"` and return the value "12"

I haven't found any code that seems to work. I have tried to use query function but it doesn't like dynamic or strings.

Edit: Created an example sheet 
Summary and Source data 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NkCAMrymdPcN29oi_DpHtKbYh7w9tPODzBqU_aCmtnk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Comment: added the sheet in an edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really sure you need **`IMPORTRANGE`** then it would be like this:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1NkCAMrymdPcN29oi_DpHtKbYh7w9tPODzBqU_aCmtnk", "Source!E1:K6"),
 "select Col"&MATCH(B$1, 
       IMPORTRANGE("1NkCAMrymdPcN29oi_DpHtKbYh7w9tPODzBqU_aCmtnk", "Source!E1:K1"), 0)&" 
  where Col1='"&$A2&"'", 0)
```

[image: 0]

Otherwise, it could be just:

[image: 0]